# Difficulty simplifying nested sums with different variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm trying to work out an algorithm analysis problem, and I'm having some difficulty determining how a jump is made between two steps in the answer.

$$
\begin{align} &\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n^2+n-i^2-i \\ = {} &\frac{1}{2}\left((n-1)n^2 + (n-1)n - \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - n^2\right) -      \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n\right)\right)\end{align}$$

I'm failing to see how this is arrived at.

I get that sum of the first $n$ and $n^2$ numbers are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two terms in the sum, $n^2$ and $n$ do not depend on $i$. As there are $n-1$ values of $i$ considered, we just multiply each of them by $n-1$.  You know $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac 16n(n+1)(2n+1)$, but the sum you are asking about is missing the final term, so we subtract $n^2$ from this result.  The same thing happens with the sum of $i$.  The sum you are asking about stops at $n-1$, so we subtract $n$ from the sum up to $n$.